# $wpdb - do you have to use foreach even if there will always only be one result?

Tags: wpdb

I have a $wpdb query that will always **only** return one result. This is a simplified version of it:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT name FROM testTable WHERE id=1" );
```

Do I have to use foreach to get that single result?

```
foreach ($results as $result ) {
   $name = $result->name;
}
```

Or can I skip the foreach and instead do something like this:

```
$name = $result->name[0];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable):

> The `get_var` function returns a **single variable** from the database. Though only one variable is returned, the entire result of the query is cached for later use. Returns **NULL** if no result is found.

```
<?php $wpdb->get_var( 'query', column_offset, row_offset ); ?>
```

So for you its:

```
$name = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT name FROM testTable WHERE id=1");
```

If you want a row use [`get_row`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row):

> To retrieve an entire **row** from a query, use **get_row**. The function can return the **row** as an **object**, an **associative array**, or as a **numerically indexed array**. If more than one row is returned by the query, only the specified row is returned by the function, but all rows are cached for later use. Returns NULL if no result is found, consider this when using the returned value in arguments, see example below.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use get_row() if you need more than a single column: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Row